# Are node parent-child relationships preserved when using coder in swift?

Tags: ios, swift3, nscoding

When encoding a set of SKNodes and SKSpriteNodes, are their parent-child relationships also encoded and later decoded automatically? Or does the node tree have to be rebuilt after decoding?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

NSCoder does preserve parent-child relationships! My mistake was not calling super.encode() in one of my classes.